# How to delay a while loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, timer, while-loop

Would this code delay the time between every time the loop gets fired?

```
  while (coin.x > objYEnemy.x) {

    var delay:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);
    delay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
    delay.start();
    function runOnce(event:TimerEvent):void {
            coin.x -= 1;
    delay.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but Google "Pseudo threading in flash" and I think you'll find some interesting things. If you have an app that has multiple nested loops and object being created within those loops, you'll see a lag (my guess as to why you asked this question). The idea behind pseudo threading is to mimic being able to throw these loops in a separate processing thread by creating a timer that that runs a function until a certain condition is meant. You mimic multithreading by, basically, creating your own loop class.

Comment: Don't worry, there are only 2 loops and no objects are created in those loops, but that's for the advice. I'm definitly checking that out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  Your loop will keep running over and over (for at least 100ms while your timer waits to fire), creating a new timer every time and creating a memory leak because your timers will never get disposed of on account of their event listener.   Since your runOnce is an anonymous function, it will also get run a whole lot of times for every timer that gets created.

Without the knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, it would seem what you'll want to do is have the timer tick handler be the loop function.

```
var checkTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);
checkTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doCheck);
checkTimer.start();

function doCheck(e:Event):void {
    if(coin.x > objYEnemy.x){
        coin.x -= 1;
        //If you want this to only happen once, then add the following line:
        checkTimer.stop();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! both the awnsers explained me very well, but this code works slightly better. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. The first problem is, that the `runOnce` is undefined when the loop is run for the first time, so it won't even run once. The second problem is the sequence in which this code is executed: The loop will start a huge load of timers, until the break condition is met, which will happen as soon as some timers have triggered the execution of `runOnce`. Go with the code of LondonDrugs_MediaServ, and unregister the event listeners after you don't need the timer anymore so it can get garbage collected.